# Find all of the integer solutions of $x^3y+y^3z+z^3x=0.$

Tags: elementary-number-theory, diophantine-equations

Using Fermat's Last Theorem, find all of the integer solutions of $x^3y+y^3z+z^3x=0.$

I try to make some substiution so as to transform the equation into a form like a fermat equation but in vain, please helps.

Comment: I found a remarkable solution,but i do not have enough time to write it down.

Answer (score 2):

Consider a solution with  $\gcd(x,y,z) = 1$.  By considering primes that divide two of $x,y,z$, show that there are nonzero integers $A,B,C$ such that $x =\pm A^3 B$, $y = \pm C^3 A$, $z = \pm B^3 C$.  Now what does your equation say?

Comment: Good idea to use Fermat decent-like approach. +1.

Comment: surely you meant $x = A^3 B, y = C^3 A, z = B^3 C$ ?

Comment: Oops, yes.  Also there are $\pm 1$'s.  I'll edit.